# OpenGL - How Transparency works?

Tags: opengl

Do i need Alpha channels for transparency to work in OpenGL? can i use glBlendFunc or anything else to make somehow the Black or White color transparent/not visible? if yes, how to do it?

Comment: Anything you do is very, very likely to be as complex or more so than alpha channels.  If it's just to learn that's ok.  So what/why are you trying to avoid using alpha channels for transparency?

Comment: coz i already have images without alpha channels..

Comment: Give some more details tranparency in Opengl is too generic. What are you trying to do?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392393/opengl-set-transparent-color-for-textures/3395132#3395132 , what was the matter with my answer ? P.S., If this question is "is there another way around", there is, but it's even more complicated.

Comment: its not a duplicate, the other question if for the texture/pixel removing, this one is for global opengl transparency... which i think is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need an alpha channel in your textures. Call `discard` in your fragment shader for all fragments that match your transparency rule.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need alpha channels to use transparency. You can emulate the behaviour of color keying using shaders, or processing the image and replacing the color key with pixels with alpha = 0.0.

Notice that GPUs always allocate RGBA textures, even if you want a RGB texture. The alpha channel is still present in hardware.

Comment: "Notice that GPUs always allocate RGBA textures, even if you want a RGB texture. The alpha channel is still present in hardware." -> do you have a reference for this please ? I never heard of this, even if it makes sense.

Comment: @Calvin That comment comes from NV/AMD engineers, but i think i saw some references in slides.